# Need help in SQL constraints

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql-server, editing

let me explain my SQL server issue

We have two tables**Manholes** and **Basis**, which are related to each other by GlobalID/Guid fields.

In the Manhole table i set coded value domain for *owner* field (1.Company 2.Unknown) and in Basis table another domain for *category* field (1.CRM_ID 2. None...).

My issue is to restrict our GIS editors to do following action: when they'll choose CRM_ID **from basis** category field, editors couldn't be able to choose Unknown value **from Manholes** owner field.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  In it, you'll see that coding questions are expected to contain code.  We can't really help you with your SQL until you show us what you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.